What UK TV show featured characters travelling between parallel universes?
I watched a UK TV show that must have been created within the last 10 years. The story focused on some characters who traveled back and forth between parallel universes.

In the first episode, the main character is confronted by a knight.
In one parallel universe, the main character is a famous band member.
In one parallel universe, the world is about to end and people have built a giant bomb shelter.
In one parallel universe, the world is all dystopian and technology seems removed, and the main character is placed in a jail.
In one instance, the main character traveled between parallel universes by climbing a tree and jumping from a branch at a specific spot.

Does anyone know what TV show this is?

Is this by any chance the UK tv show: "Tripped"?
Imdb link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4699514/?ref_=tt_ov_inf
Episode descriptions: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4699514/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1
Based on your observations, it all fits: (Based on imdb descriptions)

Once a stoner, now a respectable insurance salesman, Danny Gates decides against asking his irresponsible drug-taking long-time friend Milo Edwards to be his best man at his wedding to Kate, which so upsets Milo that he overdoses on magic mushrooms and starts to hallucinate. He sees Danny as a bearded, armour-clad knight killing Callum, an assassin sent to murder Milo, before Danny disappears. 
Leaving the house Milo and Danny see a plaque on the wall to commemorate Milo as a dead rock star and they are chased by screaming fans, including Kate, who does not know who Danny is and has sex with Milo. 
Milo and Danny return to Danny's house where 'they' have been previously killed by Callum and have to stop Kate from finding the corpses. However World War Three has broken out and, after Kate and Danny have got married, they must locate the secret bunker manufactured by Goldenmire, the 'respectable' Callum's company. in the basement of their old school. 

